# Importing a Database into Drupal shows no content

Tags: database

I've been trying to get my database imported into Drupal today and I'm having quite a few issues. I'm using VDD with Vagrant / Oracle VM and everything is working properly, I have Drupal 7 up and running with no problems. I then used the drush commands to import my database into phpmyadmin, I verified the completion of this task after somebody else suggested I used Pipe Viewer.

For the drush settings.php file I used the following:

```
$databases = array (
 'default' =>
 array (
    'default' =>
    array (
     'database' => 'drupal7',
     'username' => 'root',
     'password' => 'root',
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'port' => '',
     'driver' => 'mysql',
     'prefix' => '',
    ),
 ),
);
```

At first I was getting a configuration error as I dropped the initial db to install the new one, so I ran the install.php file and I managed to get the page to render again, but with no content besides the default Drupal stuff.

Is there some sort of trick to getting the data to display? Or some way I can verify that my database imported properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you have imported to clean drupal installation a database from other d7 site?

Comment: Yes, the database shows in phpmyadmin but I can't see anything on the page content.

Comment: Pure database is not enough. You need to copy site files (files, modules)

Comment: Shouldn't it display at least something though?

Comment: Probably a lot of errors. All required modules needs to be enabled (at least)

Comment: Please make title more meaningful.